# How to: Delete a selection from a custom select?

Tags: html-select

I have a custom select dropdown. When clicking a button, I want to delete the selected option from the custom dropdown. All I've been able to do is delete from the hidden select and not the custom.

My code only deletes from the standard select, the custom select options remain unchanged in the dropdown.

```
<html>
<style>
body {
background-image:     url('https://images.adsttc.com/media/images/5016/09f4/28ba/0d15/9800/083c/large_jpg/stringio.jpg');
}
    .custom-select {
        position: relative;
        border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
        border-radius: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .custom-select select {
            display: none; 
        }

    .select-selected {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

        .select-selected:after {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            right: 10px;
            top: 15px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border: 6px solid transparent;
            border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
        }

        .select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
            border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
            top: 7px;
        }

    .select-items div, .select-selected {
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        border-radius: 40px;
        font-family: "Cinzel", serif;
    }

    .select-items {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: black;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 101;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
        border-radius: 40px;
        backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    }

    .select-hide {
        display: none;
    }

    .select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

</style>
<body>

<div class="custom-select">
  <select id="animal"></select>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction();">Remove</button>

<script>
let options = ["Select", "Elephant", "Gorilla", "Grizzly Bear", "Lion", "Polar Bear", "Rhino", "Tiger"];

const zoo = document.getElementById("animal");

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = options[i];
option.text = options[i];
zoo.appendChild(option);
}

function myFunction() {
  var zoo = document.getElementById("favteam");
  zoo.remove(zoo.selectedIndex);
 }
 </script>

   <script>

    var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;

    x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
    l = x.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        ll = selElmnt.length;

        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
        a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        x[i].appendChild(a);

        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
        for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {

            c = document.createElement("DIV");
            c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
            c.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

                var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
                s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
                sl = s.length;
                h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
                for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
                    if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                        s.selectedIndex = i;
                        h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                        y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                        yl = y.length;
                        for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
                            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                        }
                        this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                h.click();
            });
            b.appendChild(c);
        }
        x[i].appendChild(b);
        a.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            e.stopPropagation();
            closeAllSelect(this);
            this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
            this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
        });
    }
    function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {

        var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
        y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
        xl = x.length;
        yl = y.length;
        for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
            if (elmnt == y[i]) {
                arrNo.push(i)
            } else {
                y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
            if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
                x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
            }
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've provided my code in full. The issue I'm having is that I can't find a way to remove an option from a custom select list by user input (IE button click).  I code I've provided allows the option to be removed from the standard select statement but not from the custom list. I've tried a multitude of different solutions and none of them work. So instead of giving many broken ideas, I was wondering if someone had the know how and could fit it into what I already have. What I provided works in everyway except deleting from the custom select.